# Copy from one structure to another structure of different type

Tags: c++, structure

I am trying this piece of code in vs 2008

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct _first
{
    int age;
    std::string name;
}first;

typedef struct _second
{
    int age;
    char name[20];
}second;

void copy_structure()
{
    first s;
    second f;

    f.age = 15;
    cout<<"Enter the name"<<endl;
    fgets(f.name, 20, stdin);

    memcpy(&s,&f,20);

    cout << "Name: " << s.name << endl;
    cout << "Age: "<< s.age << endl;
}

int main()
{
    copy_structure();

    return 0;
}
```

while building I didn't get any error but when I run, name field is empty over here

```
cout << "Name: " << s.name << endl;
```

I am not getting any output over here, can somebody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Why would there be a name there? What on earth convinced you that you can simply bitwise copy a `char` buffer into a `std::string` *object* and get a valid string?

Comment: FYI: `struct _second` is larger than 20 bytes. Although that is not your biggest issue.

Comment: why not specify the requirements you are burdened with, and get a solution for them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an approach based on member-wise copying. For example

```
void copy_structure()
{
    first f;
          ^^
    second s;
           ^^

    s.age = 15;
    cout<<"Enter the name"<<endl;
    fgets(s.name, 20, stdin);

    f.age = s.age;
    f.name = s.name;

    cout << "Name: " << f.name << endl;
    cout << "Age: "<< f.age << endl;
}
```

Otherwise the internals of the object name of the type `std::string` will be overwritten and the program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NIXIN You may not do that way as you are going to do.:)

Comment: what are the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like C but not like C++... Your current code will also brick your std::string instance. memcpy is dangerous and should not be used, unless you have a very, very good reason. I never had a reason for this so far.

My suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct second
{
    int age;
    char name[20];
};

struct first
{
    int age;
    string name;

    first& operator=(const second& rhs);
};

// some operator for copying
first& first::operator=(const second& rhs)
{
    age = rhs.age;
    name = rhs.name;

    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    first s;
    second f;

    f.age = 15;
    cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
    cin >> f.name;

    s = f;

    cout << "Name: " << s.name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << s.age << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is improvable, of course. You would usually rather use classes than structs. And you would might also have an operator>> for second.